# MySQL query to find the best accomodation for best prices

Tags: mysql

I have a table "residence" like this:

```
CREATE TABLE residence (nameRoom varchar(100), idRoom int primary key,guest int, price int);

INSERT INTO residence (nameRoom, idRoom,guest,price) VALUES 
('camera 1', 1,2,200),
('camera 2', 2,2,200),
('camera 3', 3,3,300),
('camera 4', 4,2,400),
('camera 5', 5,4,200),
('camera 6', 6,6,500);
```

I'm looking to write a SQL which will give me the best accomodation in rooms with the best prices.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And define 'best'.

Comment: funny - which one do you think best one put it id in where clause .

Comment: The best price is the cheapest one. For example for 5 guests the better solutions is 
camera1+camera3 because the price is 500

Comment: This question is extremely poor quality, but I think I understand what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). You can't find a simple query to solve it. The problem is NP-complete.

Comment: Within a limited scale, this problem can be solved using a simple query. It just might not be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea...

```
 SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ',r1.nameroom,r2.nameroom,r3.nameroom) rooms
      , r1.price+COALESCE(r2.price,0)+COALESCE(r3.price,0) total_cost
      , r1.guest+COALESCE(r2.guest,0)+COALESCE(r3.guest,0) guests
   FROM residence r1 
   LEFT 
   JOIN residence r2 
     ON r2.idroom < r1.idroom 
   LEFT 
   JOIN residence r3 
     ON r3.idroom < r2.idroom
 HAVING  guests >= 5
  ORDER
     BY total_cost;

+------------------------------+------------+--------+
| rooms                        | total_cost | guests |
+------------------------------+------------+--------+
| camera 5, camera 1           |        400 |      6 |
| camera 3, camera 1           |        500 |      5 |
| camera 5, camera 2, camera 1 |        600 |      8 |
| camera 3, camera 2, camera 1 |        700 |      7 |
| camera 5, camera 3, camera 2 |        700 |      9 |
| camera 6, camera 1           |        700 |      8 |
| camera 5, camera 3, camera 1 |        700 |      9 |
| camera 5, camera 4, camera 1 |        800 |      8 |
| camera 4, camera 2, camera 1 |        800 |      6 |
| camera 5, camera 4, camera 2 |        800 |      8 |
| camera 5, camera 4, camera 3 |        900 |      9 |
| camera 6, camera 5, camera 1 |        900 |     12 |
| camera 4, camera 3, camera 2 |        900 |      7 |
| camera 6, camera 5, camera 2 |        900 |     12 |
| camera 6, camera 2, camera 1 |        900 |     10 |
| camera 4, camera 3, camera 1 |        900 |      7 |
| camera 6, camera 3, camera 2 |       1000 |     11 |
| camera 6, camera 5, camera 3 |       1000 |     13 |
| camera 6, camera 3, camera 1 |       1000 |     11 |
| camera 6, camera 4, camera 1 |       1100 |     10 |
| camera 6, camera 4, camera 2 |       1100 |     10 |
| camera 6, camera 5, camera 4 |       1100 |     12 |
| camera 6, camera 4, camera 3 |       1200 |     11 |
+------------------------------+------------+--------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Strawberry. I will use your solution to solve my problem. Sorry if I failed to express well my problem, but my English vocabulary is narrow