# Inserting data recursively into table to find route

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I am trying to implement a metro rail shortest path algorithm in MySQL.
Below is one of the tables 'station' and the map it is based upon.

The idea basically is to

1. Create a new table 'route' with single column. Acting as a stack.
2. inputting the start and the destination station.

Since I am showing only one table for simplicity, lets say I want to go from **G1 to RG**.
So my 'route' table should have 3 rows - G1, G2, RG

and I plan to **use the Next_Station column (foreign key to Station_ID) to insert these**.

like Insert the start (G1), insert its next (G2), insert its next (RG), dest reached so terminate

So, can someone give me an idea on how to start and what is necessary (procedure, trigger, CTE, function) because I don't have much practice experience in how to actually implement them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect you know this already, but np-complete problems are not what sql is good at

Comment: @Strawberry but still since the project i work on insist that (My)sql is the main concept

Comment: how do you know RG and RY are two station next to each other?

Comment: @eshirvana because I also have a 'hybrid' table that has 2 rows for the two junctions and holds data about the stations connected to the junction.

Comment: @eshirvana For simplicity, I didn't posted my entire database and that's why I didn't use such an example where it would be necessary

Comment: but that would affect the solution. for example if i want to find a route from R1 to R3 .based on current data i never can find a route

Comment: @eshirvana yes you are correct but I want an idea on how to attempt the simple problem and then I will be looking at the ones that include junction

Comment: See for instance answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346249/mysql-query-to-find-the-best-accomodation-for-best-prices/39354599#39354599

Comment: For inspiration, I'd look at [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), this seems to be similar to what you vaguely have in mind as a strategy. As Strawberry said, it's not something you should do in sql, but you may want to try out [this implementation](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=766&m=0), at least to get an idea of what direction you may need to go. I'd also recheck if the premise *"but still since the project i work on insist that (My)sql is the main concept"* does exclude to just load the data into your app and solve it there.